# Specialize one function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++23

There's two things I'd like to specialize. An `int`, and any type of pointer. But let's stick with `int` for now.

In the below code, if `T` is an `int`, I'd like a different implementation of `Test::a()` which returns 0. I tried:

```
template<>
int a() { return 0; }
```

but that's obviously wrong, as I got a compile error suggesting what I wrote made no sense.

Is there a way I can do this? Do I need to specialize all of `Test` if I want to do something like this?

My real class is a few hundred lines, so I would rather only reimplement the one or two functions, if possible.

```
template<class T>
class Test{
    T*t;
public:
    Test(T*t) : t(t) {}

    T a() { return 1; }
    T b() { return 2; }
    //if T == int
    //int a() { return 0; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test<int> t(0);
    return t.a();
}
```

Comment: You can do this with `if constexpr`, try to learn it.

Comment: You don't need to specialize anything (What  
康桓瑋 said, 7 seconds before me).  Do you simply want `a()` to return `0` when `T` is `int`?  Or do you really have some need to use specialization to solve this problem?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Oh oops. I never actually seen code that uses it but I think I overheard about it in passing. I'll give it a shot. -Edit- worked in this one case. Now I'll try in real code. I'll accept your comment if you paste it as an answer

Comment: If you really must then, after the template class definition, add `template<> int Test<int>::a() {return 0;}`.

Comment: @Peter thanks that worked as well. I'll use this if I need to support older versions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specialization is arguably overkill for this sort of problem.

You can use **constexpr if** (which is spelled `if constexpr`) to achieve this just as efficiently as specialization would, in a single function.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class Test{
    T*t;
public:
    Test(T*t) : t(t) {}

    T a() {
      if constexpr ( std::is_same_v<T,int> ) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    T b() { return 2; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test<int> t(0);
    return t.a();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned you don't need to use specialization to accomplish this anymore.  If you can't use C++17 or newer for some reason then you can still use specialization, and the syntax for that is:

```
template<> int Test<int>::a() { return 0; }
^          ^        ^
|          |        +- template type to specialize
|          |
|          +- the return type you want to have for the specialization
|
+- specify that you are defining a specialization
```

You can see this working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e7cb0ab93e13781)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best solution, but one way of doing it is by implementing the whole class again for the edge case. as in:

```
template<class T>
class Test{
    T*t;
public:
    Test(T*t) : t(t) {}

    T a() { return 1; }
    T b() { return 2; }
};

// handles all pointer cases
template <class T>
class Test<T*> {
    T** t;
  public:
    Test (T** t): t(t) {}
    T* a() { return nullptr; }
    T* b() { return nullptr; }
};

// handles int specifically 
template <>
class Test <int> {
    int* t;
  public:
    Test (int* t): t(t) {}
    int a() { return 0; }
    int b() { return 42; }
};
```